# android browser with built-in debugging tools

Tags: android, web, mobile, browser

Is there any browser for Android that has the nice debugging tools we have in desktop browsers? (js console and such). At least I didn't find any option to enable debugging tools in Chrome for Android. I know the common approach for debugging is to connect the phone to an external computer, but sometimes I want to just do some quick debugging in the phone itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if what you're asking for exists, but in case you didn't know, you can open developer tools in chrome f12 and click on the context menu next to "X"  and in the "more tools" menu there is something called remote devices where you can debug and liveinspect your webview.

Comment: I'm aware of the regular debugging tools, but I was looking for an option to do it in the phone without an additional computer. I was expecting to find at least a mobile browser aimed at developers with a basic js console, but I haven't found anything like that.